# Why Is jQuery Not Submitting This Form? (Or What Have I Done Wrong? :-p)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit, opayo

HTML:

```
<form action="https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" method="POST" id="sagepay_form"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="navigate" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="2.23">
    <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT">
    <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="******************">
    <input type="hidden" id= "Crypt" name="Crypt" value="">
    <input id="payment_proceed" value="Proceed To Payment" class="mws-button green" type="button">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#payment_proceed").click(function() {
        $.post('/includes/cart/ajax/sagepay.php', { //This script just echos the base64 "Crypt" string required by sagepay.
                "cart_id": <?php echo $cart_id; ?>,
                "title": $("#title").val(),
                "first_name": $("#first_name").val(),
                "last_name": $("#last_name").val(),
                "telephone": $("#telephone").val(),
                "email": $("#email").val(),
                "line1": $("#line1").val(),
                "line2": $("#line2").val(),
                "line3": $("#line3").val(),
                "town": $("#town").val(),
                "county": $("#county").val(),
                "postcode": $("#postcode").val()
            },
            function(crypt){              
                $("#Crypt").val(crypt); //The base64 "Crypt" string is inserted in to the hidden form field here.
                alert($("#Crypt").val()); //I just put this here to make sure it had received the "Crypt" string.
                $("#sagepay_form").submit(); //This doesn't work...
            });
    });
```

I have no idea why $("#sagepay_form").submit(); does not submit the form. My only guess is it's because the "action" url is a remote server. If this is the case, does anyone know how I can go about what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the alert for `alert($("#Crypt").val());` ? Also note that the action url being remote will not be an issue since you are doing a standard form submit and not an AJAX POST request (in which case you'll get a cross-domain security exception from the browser).

Comment: This code looks legit, getting any errors in console?

Comment: Why mix JS and PHP if you're using AJAX? Seems contradictory...

Comment: check JS console and tell us the error.

Comment: Yup, the Crypt alert works fine, I just added an alert for $cart_id and that is ok. I realised I hadn't put " around the echo so I've done that and still nothing.

No errors in console either.

Comment: Sorry, just tried it in jsfiddle and got an error in console: TypeError:

$("#payment_proceed") is null

$("#payment_proceed").click(function() {

Comment: $("form#sagepay_form").submit();

Comment: @Svetlio That didn't work either

Comment: you dont have submit input that is the problem I guess.. 
I am not sure but if you try with class not id it may work ..
there was little trick when you dont have submit input

Comment: If you say that alert works fine then it is not a problem,Apparently you didnt included jQuery when running this on fiddle.

Comment: @Svetlio I put a submit button in with visibility:hidden and still get the same result.

Comment: @techie_28 I realised that was the problem, I've since moved this code to a fresh folder on my localhost away from all my other code and ran it with no console errors at all but it just won't submit. I have no idea what's going on. The POST returns 200 OK and after that.. nothing.

Comment: Please share the fiddle view for us.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mQaP4/7/ Well I took out the ajax code as the Crypt is all done via. a local file and just set the value of Crypt straight away and this works fine on fiddle, it doesn't however work on my local server. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is it showing the same TypeError on your local server?Please use the console and tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$("#sagepay_form").submit(function()` ...instead of `$("#payment_proceed").click(function()`.