# Sagepay - straight forward PHP form

Tags: php, jquery, opayo

It would appear that access to Sagepay resources to just make a simple payment form is quite limited.

I am trying to create a simple form that submits to SagePay with a fixed GBP value. I have used the code posted here:

[Why Is jQuery Not Submitting This Form? (Or What Have I Done Wrong? :-p)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207815/why-is-jquery-not-submitting-this-form-or-what-have-i-done-wrong-p)

However, the issue I have is that I am missing their referenced fix 'includes/cart/ajax/sagepay.php' which I believe takes the values and encrypts them as Base64. Does anyone have any advice on how I could recreate such a file to return the value in the format I need?

Answer (score 2):

Check out my sagepay form class https://github.com/tolzhabayev/sagepayForm-php

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use these classes for PHP. 
https://code.google.com/p/sagepay-form-class/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded one of the Integration Kits from their [support page](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration)?

I was able to take a .dll file from the .NET version (I'm working in .NET, though, which no doubt helps) and use a function which appears in there to do the encoding.  However, I'm trying to do something as simple as you are and still failing thus far.